# Adding this instance variable to the header of a C++11 file drives the compiler up the wall. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, instance-variables

I've been trying to get my artificial intelligence program (written in C++11) to stop spewing out error messages larger than my Terminal will record. I've withered away methods one at a time until the message went away, and have hence found the precise line which makes the computer go bonkers. Here's the pertinent part of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>

class H
{
    public:
        H(int);
        int get_val();
    private:
        int val;
};

class Hvote
{
    public:
        Hvote() : error(1.0) { }
        std::vector<H&> hs;
        double error;
};

int main()
{
    Hvote hvote;
    return 0;
}
```

To me, it all looks reasonable. However, the compiler (g++) disagrees. The error messages are so long that my Terminal doesn't even bother saving the beginning, so I don't know their true length. However, they're pretty repetitive. The last page, for instance, reads:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::vector<H&>’:
hvote.h:16:25:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:237:20: error: no members matching ‘std::vector<H&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >}::_M_allocate’ in ‘std::vector<H&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >}’
   using _Base::_M_allocate;
                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:238:20: error: no members matching ‘std::vector<H&>::_Base {aka std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >}::_M_deallocate’ in ‘std::vector<H&>::_Base {aka struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >}’
   using _Base::_M_deallocate;
                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:878:7: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘H&’
   data() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:886:7: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘H&’
   data() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:919:7: error: ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = H&; _Alloc = std::allocator<H&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = H&]’ cannot be overloaded
   push_back(value_type&& __x)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: error: with ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = H&; _Alloc = std::allocator<H&>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = H&]’
   push_back(const value_type& __x)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = H&; _Alloc = std::allocator<H&>]’:
hvote.h:10:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416:30: error: ‘struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >::_Vector_impl’ has no member named ‘_M_start’
     _M_get_Tp_allocator()); }
                          ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416:30: error: ‘struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >::_Vector_impl’ has no member named ‘_M_finish’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::~_Vector_base() [with _Tp = H&; _Alloc = std::allocator<H&>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:416:33:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = H&; _Alloc = std::allocator<H&>]’
hvote.h:10:7:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:161:33: error: ‘struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >::_Vector_impl’ has no member named ‘_M_start’
     - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: ‘struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >::_Vector_impl’ has no member named ‘_M_start’
     - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: ‘struct std::_Vector_base<H&, std::allocator<H&> >::_Vector_impl’ has no member named ‘_M_end_of_storage’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:161:33: error: ‘_M_deallocate’ was not declared in this scope
     - this->_M_impl._M_start); }
                             ^
```

However, there's only one little change I need to make so that this all goes away. In `hvote.h`, just delete the line, `std::vector<H&> hs;`. Now everything works perfectly! What's the problem with that line? (In my not-reduced and much longer original program, `hs` is a variable I need, as opposed to here where I've paired away all the methods of `hvote` that use it)
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you expect a vector of references to do

Comment: By the way - if you're getting build spew that overruns your terminal's capability to scrollback, then create a build log.  This command will let you see the progress on the terminal as well as capture all messages to a log file: `command-used-to-build 2>&1 | tee build-console-output.log`.  Now you can open the log file in an editor and see everything that happened in the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has a problem with you keeping a vector of non-const references

```
std::vector<H&> hs;
```

I would suggest maintaining either a vector of values or pointers, depending on if you want to own these `H` instances or just reference them.

```
std::vector<H> hs;
std::vector<H*> hs;
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed std::vector<H&> to std::vector<H> and it all works just fine.

Comment: Or `std::reference_wrapper<H>` if you want something more "referencey" than pointers.

Comment: @QuantumFool it is polite to select a correct, and especially a helpful answer.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum What do you mean by "select"? I'd be happy to do something to promote this answer - it was very helpful.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't heard of those. I actually got the code to work in a way that I could ditch the references all together, but I'll remember that if I have this problem again in the future :)

Comment: @QuantumFool See [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), specifically the section on voting and accepting answers. Also, you even get a badge for reading it and badges are cool.